# One extract pump to multi target with encrypt in oracle golden gate

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle-golden-gate

I have one primary extract change capture and one secondary extract pump as below :

EXTRACT EXTFINA2 
-- primary extract 
SOURCEDB mydb UserIDAlias gguser 
ENCRYPTTRAIL AES256 
EXTTRAIL ./dirdat/extfina2/f2 
TABLE source_user.t1;

EXTRACT PUMFINA2 
--secondary extract 
SOURCEDB mydb UserIDAlias gguser 
RMTHOST 192.168.1.10, MGRPORT 7600, ENCRYPT AES256, TCPBUFSIZE 100000, TCPFLUSHBYTES 300000, NOSTREAMING 
RMTTRAIL ./dirdat/repfina2/f2 
TABLE source_user.t1;

RMTHOST 192.168.1.20, MGRPORT 7600, ENCRYPT AES256, TCPBUFSIZE 100000, TCPFLUSHBYTES 300000, NOSTREAMING 
RMTTRAIL ./dirdat/repfina2/f2 
TABLE source_user.t1;

but I always get error ERROR  OGG-01232 Receive TCP params error: TCP/IP error 104 (Connection reset by peer), endpoint: 192.168.1.10:7611

When I remove ENCRYPT in RMTHOST 192.168.1.20 as below, It is working fine.

EXTRACT PUMFINA2 
--secondary extract 
SOURCEDB mydb UserIDAlias gguser 
RMTHOST 192.168.1.10, MGRPORT 7600, ENCRYPT AES256, TCPBUFSIZE 100000, TCPFLUSHBYTES 300000, NOSTREAMING 
RMTTRAIL ./dirdat/repfina2/f2 
TABLE source_user.t1; 
RMTHOST 192.168.1.20, MGRPORT 7600 
RMTTRAIL ./dirdat/repfina2/f2 
TABLE source_user.t1;

Have anyone can help me why I can't enable ENCRYPT in two RMTHOST.

Comment: Anyone can help. Please

Answer (score 0):

Does pump uses winrm service on 192.168.1.20 ?
Check the winrm listener to see if it listens on 7611.
It creates the server collector process on the target server, so you might as well check the port 7611 is opened.